# How to filter from string vector c++ instead of new vector

Tags: c++, vector

In C++, I start with a vector matchingFirstAndLast, which is filled with words that match some criteria (based on userInput). On average, its very large, so I apply filters on it and create a vector to store what was filtered. I feel like that is not elegant; I would like to filter (like for F# lists) instead of making a new vector.

In other words, I want to have one vector that gets filtered over and over without creating new ones.

```
My code's data flow :: matchingFirstAndLast |> sequenced |> appropriateLength |> finalSuggestions`
```

// My code ( in case needed )

```
vector<finalwords> compute      (string userInput,
                                 vector<string>dictionary,
                                 vector<string>popular,
                                 vector<string>keyboard_layout)
{
  //matchingFirstAndLast will hold words with the same first and last letter as the input string
  vector<string>matchingFirstAndLast;
  int inputLength = userInput.length();

  //for every word in the big dictionary vector, look for first and last letter similarites
  for (string &x : dictionary)
    if (userInput[0] == x.front() && userInput[inputLength - 1] == x.back())
      matchingFirstAndLast.push_back (x);

  //sequenced will hold words whose letters are found in sequence in the userInput string
  vector<string>sequenced;

  for (string &x : matchingFirstAndLast)
    if (FoundInSequence (userInput, x))
      sequenced.push_back (x);

  //determine the minimum word length based on the number of times the string changes
  //rows on the keyboard.
  int minLength = GetMinWordLength (userInput, keyboard_layout);

  //appropriateLength will hold all words longer than the minLength
  vector<string>appropriateLength;

  for (auto &x : sequenced)
    if (x.length() > minLength || minLength < 0)
      appropriateLength.push_back (x);

  vector<finalwords> finalSuggestions;

  for (string &x : appropriateLength)
    if (find (popular.begin(), popular.end(), x) != popular.end()) //word found in popular.txt
      finalSuggestions.push_back (finalwords (x, true, true, edit_distance (userInput, x)));
    else
      finalSuggestions.push_back (finalwords (x, false, true, edit_distance (userInput, x)));

  //sort the returned vector by most popular first
  sortResults (finalSuggestions);

  return finalSuggestions;
}//end compute(...)
```

**In python**, for example, this is possible

```
suggestions = filter(lambda x: x[0] == path[0] and x[-1] == path[-1], WORDS)
suggestions = filter(lambda x: match(path, x), suggestions)
suggestions = filter(lambda x: len(x) > min_length, suggestions)
```

This never stores the 'filtered' data into a new container.

Like the python example ^, I would like some way of doing this in C++

Comment: You are copying the vector when you call the function: consider changing the inputs from vector<string> to const vector<string> &dictionary

Answer (score 1):

'Filter' is a bit ambiguous.  From my perspective when you say you're trying to 'filter' a `vector` it implies, to me, that you want to create another `vector` with only some of the elements from the original list.  But the text of your post makes it clear that that's *not* what you want.  So my conclusion is what you're really after is *selective iteration* of the elements in the `vector`.  In other words, you want to iterate over the elements in the list, but only act on some of them.

If that's the case, then I'd suggest using a fictional Std Lib algorithm, `for_each_if`.  I say fictional because there is no such algorithm, but I've implemented it in the past and it's not hard.

Something along these lines should about do it (untested):

```
template <typename InIt, typename Predicate, typename UnaryFunction>
UnaryFunction for_each_if (InIt first, InIt last, UnaryFunction fn, Predicate pr)
{
  for (; first != last; ++first)
  {
    if (pr (*first))
      fn (*first);
  }
  return fn;
}
```

Using this is similar to using `std::for_each`, except you also specify a predicate like you would with `copy_if`.  Assuming C++11, you could do all of this with lambdas.

Answer (score 1):

Think of implementing your own type of iterator that will return strings that correspond to some set of predicates.
Example pseudocode:

```
struct iter {
    std::vector<Predicate> predicates;
    std::vector<string>&   values;
    int currentValue = 0;

    string nextValue() {
        return values[currentValue++];
    }

    bool hasValue() {
        while (currentValue < values.count() {
            bool found = true;
            for (auto& pred : predicates)
                if (!pred(values[currentValue])) {
                    ++currentValue; found = false; break;
                }
            if (found) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

On the other hand you may search for some implementations of LINQ for C++.
I've implmented one by myself:
[github](https://github.com/nikitoz/cpp_linq) It is not for production use, but you may find some ideas interesting.